# How can I import tasks into the backlog in Azure Devops from SQL

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I’m working with Azure DevOps and Microsoft Service Manager 2019. We use Service Manager to create incident tickets and we now have a lot of them.

The tickets from Service Manager are stored in a database in SQL Server Management Studio. I need to transfer the incident tickets from Service Manager to the Azure DevOps backlog as work items. Is this possible?

I was thinking of a way to sync the SQL Server database with Azure SQL and create a pipeline that takes the SQL Server data and transforms it into a CSV file. Then, I could create another task to import the CSV file into the backlog. Is this possible? Or is there another way to import the Service Manager incidents into the backlog?

Comment: You could always just iterate over your SQL Server data, and call the Azure Devops API to create work items from your SQL Server data items.